# Overflow-y:scroll won't Display scrollbar in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I build a code-highlighter for our blog and run into a problem with the Internet Explorer
For example on [this blog post](http://www.lundp.de/blog/posts/2015/september/umbraco-anpassung-von-social-media-buttons-an-das-eigene-corporate-design/) I pasted some html code. I don't want to add a `white-space:pre` to break the code in more lines, instead I set `overflow-y:auto` on the xmp-Tag instead so that a the user can scroll through the code.
This works fine on Firefox but InternetExplorer won't display the scrollbar.

I added `white-space:pre-wrap` on the linked site as a work around, if you remove the css-property you can see that Firefox adds the scrollbar, also here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If you want horizontal-scroll then it should be `overflow-x: auto;` And `overflow: auto` will be much better option.

Comment: But this won't solve the problem. There is still no scrollbar.

Comment: I don't get a horizontal scrollbar in any browser with that page. Wait, is that a `xmp` element? Are you serious?

Comment: I just updated the synthax highlighter editor I created. And didn't had time to build a script the escape html characters. And you don't see the scroll bar because, as mentioned, I added `white-space:pre-wrap` so that my live website isn't ruined. If you remove the `white-space` css from `<pre class="prettyprint">` children the scrollbar should be visible in Firefox.

Comment: Can you make an example, in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something, that demonstrates the issue? If your own website is currently being changed, it's a moving target and any kind of answer would be outdated almost as soon as it's posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that the problem was that I wrapped the code in a `<xmp>`-tag. Firefox and Co can handle the xmp-tag except for IE. Changed the xmp-Tag to a `<pre>` tag and the overflow property creates a scrollbar.